# How to implement Launch4j inside a java program

Tags: java, launch4j

Is there any way to convert a jar file to an exe file in Launch4j .
Like 
new L4j.build(File jar,File exe);

Comment: You would normally do this with some sort of build-management-tool like maven or gradle. Are you having a specific problem you want to solve?

Comment: Is it possible in net beans

Comment: @S.Baner if it 's possible to call it in java, it's possible in netbeans. but why would you want to?

Comment: I want to create an IDE that would first build a jar file from a java source code and then convert it into an exe file.The whole process would go programmatically without any interference of Launch4j window